# CMake total test timeout

Tags: cmake

To set timeout for certain test we can use

> set_tests_properties(mytest PROPERTIES
>   TIMEOUT 4)

I am searching way to set timeout for whole testsuite. Is there any way to pass some code to CTestTestfile.cmake from CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried any of these myself, I just remembered I had seen something like this in the CTest sourcecode.

I found a variable called CTEST_TIME_LIMIT that should do what you want, but it seems to only work if you are running the tests from a CTest script.

There also seems to be an argument --stop-time for ctest, that takes the time of day when all tests must stop running. I actually can't think of a way to use this unless starting all tests manually.